# AngularJS directives - directives on transcluded content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/XbgMa9681GkKPeodplJx?p=preview

Please see the above plunker.  Is there a way to bind directives in template dom to the parent directive's scope?  I've seen this behavior with ng-transclude as well, the above is just about as simple as I can make it.  I have read that transcluded content is in a scope which is a sibling of the directive scope but $$nextSibling doesn't seem to be the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

use directive:

```
app.directive('accordion', function($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'C',
      scope: { 

      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.showSection = false;
        elem.find('p').attr('ng-show', 'false');
        $compile(elem.find('p'))(scope)
        elem.find('h1, h2').bind('click', function () {
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.showSection = !scope.showSection; 
            elem.find('p').attr('ng-show', 'showSection');
            $compile(elem.find('p'))(scope);
          });
        });
      }
  };
});
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWaiB0q0ojVPgBmKreWm?p=preview)